# Get dimension objects using acad.net

Tags: .net, vb.net-2010, autocad, autocad-plugin

I need to get the bounding box detail of a dimension text in ACAD using .NET, Is there any in-built options available?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to take a subentity selection of the Dimension, then from that entity you can parse its geometric extents. Good luck!